# I have installed Lince Bi on Windows machine but on connecting SQL server it is showing SSL error

Tags: pentaho

I have installed Lince Bi on Windows machine but on connecting SQL server it is showing SSL error.

"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "No trusted certificate found". ClientConnectionId:92c4c4cd-5088-45d0-97c6-363303c25af1
"

I already added trust certificate

Answer (score 0):

If the driver keeps failing with the encryption error, make sure to provide the "Encrypt=false" parameter to the data source.

[image: DataSource]

[image: Encrypt Parameter]

You need to provide the apropriate Microsoft JDBC driver in order to LinceBI work correctly as well.

You can download it from Microsoft: [Download Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)

I use mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre8.jar because I'm using Java JDK 8.
The driver must be put inside the lincebi_web\tomcat\lib directory.

Best Regards!